# Uploaded Certificate Visible in Multiple Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have successfully uploaded a certificate to an Azure web app via the portal.  I was surprised to also see it in other web apps in the same resource group.  Is that the expected behavior?  I also created a new App Service Plan for one of the sites, but the certificate was still showing in the other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It’s important to note that Certificates are now part of the Resource
>   Group itself, and can be assigned to multiple web sites within that
>   Resource Group.

According to this [documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2015/01/31/azure-resource-manager-adding-and-assigning-certificates-to-a-website.aspx)

So it's expected behavior.

Comment: This came to be as a surprise too. The documentation link here seems to have moved. Are you able to point to the new document?